# Azure configuration with multiple tasks possible?

Tags: azure, startup

We have a third party .NET application which comes with its' own deployment tool. This deployment tool generates a custom startup.cmd file. We have an option to modify the CFG file but not the cmd file.

I would like to have my own cmd file. Could someone please confirm whether multiple tasks are allowed in a cloud service definition file?

For example...

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine=”thirdpartyPropietryStartup1.cmd” executionContext=”elevated” />    
  <Task commandLine=”startup\startup2.cmd” executionContext=”elevated” />
</Startup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple startup tasks should work according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx).

It is not that explicit but it states that

> simple tasks are executed synchronously, one at a time, in the order specified in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

which would make no sense if multiple tasks would not work.

If there are issues you could always create a *combined.cmd* which runs *thirdpartyPropietryStartup1.cmd* and then *startup\startup2.cmd* (unless your executionContext should be different).