# Is it available multi task tag in <StartUp> or do I have to merge these cmd files to only one?

Tags: powershell, azure, startup

I am new Azure development and writing powershell script.

I want to run two cmd files for azure start up tasks. I added these files into solutions and set properties as "**copy always**".After I add new note into **ServiceDefinition.csdef** Here it is :

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Startup\startupcmd.cmd &gt; c:\logs\startuptasks.log" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background">
    <Environment>
      <Variable name="EMULATED">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
      </Variable>
    </Environment>
  </Task>
  <Task commandLine="Startup\disableTimeout.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

It's not deploying and getting this error : **Instance 0 of role Web is busy**

Now In my question : Is it available multi task tag in <**StartUp**> or do I have to merge these cmd files to only one ?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985215/azure-configuration-with-multiple-tasks-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx#Startup):

> The **Startup** element describes *a collection of tasks* that run when the
>   role is started.

So yes, the answer to your concrete question is: Yes, you can define multiple startup tasks.

State Busy is almost fine, in terms it is bit better than cycling! What I would suggest it to enable Remote Desktop and connect to see what is going on with the start up task. Busy is set until all **simple** tasks have completed and returned 0 exit code. Your task may fail or may hang for a while and that's why you would see busy.